# Android inner and outer class dilemma

Tags: android, class

I have found myself inside a odd situation which I have been trying to solve for a couple of hours.

Here is my boolean method inside my Main Activity java file

```
public boolean AutoSlowColorChange(boolean SlowOn) {

    if (SlowOn) {

        final Random rand = new Random();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                int Changecolor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));

                ObjectAnimator ChangecolorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(screen, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(),
                        Color.argb(Changecolor, Changecolor, Changecolor, Changecolor), Changecolor);
                //slow change
                ChangecolorFade.setDuration(2000);
                ChangecolorFade.start();


                ChangecolorFade.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
                ChangecolorFade.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);

                int value = rand.nextInt(10);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 4000);


            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    } else {
        ChangecolorFade.end();
        ChangecolorFade.cancel();
    }

        return SlowOn;

}
```

i am trying to stop the ObjectAnimator inside the else statement

```
} else {
    ChangecolorFade.end();
    ChangecolorFade.cancel();
}
```

it can not be reached because it is inside Runnable(), now if I place the ObjectAnimator in the beginning of the method so it will be read by both Runnable and the else statement

```
 public boolean AutoSlowColorChange(boolean SlowOn) {
            int Changecolor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
        ObjectAnimator ChangecolorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(screen, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(),
                Color.argb(Changecolor, Changecolor, Changecolor, Changecolor), Changecolor);
```

I will have to declare it as final

```
public boolean AutoSlowColorChange(boolean SlowOn) {
            int Changecolor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
        final ObjectAnimator ChangecolorFade = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(screen, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(),
                Color.argb(Changecolor, Changecolor, Changecolor, Changecolor), Changecolor);
```

If I declare it as final, it will be read by Runnable() and the else statement however because it is final I am unable to randomly change the color

I have also tried to place the Changecolor int inside the public main method however no luck. And if I create another ObjectAnimator under

```
public boolean AutoSlowColorChange(boolean SlowOn) {
ObjectAnimator ChangecolorFade2 = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(screen, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(),
        Color.argb(Changecolor, Changecolor, Changecolor, Changecolor), Changecolor);
```

It will not be able to stop the current Animation from running.

Does anyone have any ideas for this dilemma I'm in? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring your animator final doesn't make it immutable. If I get it right, you can update the color values at any moment with the ObjectAnimator's setObjectValues(Object... values) method.

Alternatively, it seems, that you can mutate the Changecolor after the object animator has been created.